# Min(date) returning conflicting Results - Tableau

Tags: sql, date, min, tableau-api

Long time observer, first time poster:

I'm currently using the SQL capabilities in Tableau. I would like the query to return userid (SQLCEC), the date of attendance (SQL Date), and the first time that user has ever attended (FirstAttendanceDate).

```
SELECT [Attendees$].[CEC] AS [SQLCEC]

, [Attendees$].[Date] AS [SQL Date]
, [Data2].[FirstAttendanceDate]       

FROM [Attendees$]
INNER JOIN(SELECT [Attendees$].[Name]
,                  MIN([Attendees$].[Date])As [FirstAttendanceDate]
                   From [Attendees$]
                   Group By [Attendees$].[Name])AS [Data2]
ON [Attendees$].[Name] = [Data2].[Name]
WHERE [Attendees$].[CEC] IN ("jakyles","ajannett")
ORDER BY [Attendees$].[CEC],[Attendees$].[Date]
```

The code returns the following results:

```
SQLCEC    SQL Date          FirstAttendanceDate
ajannett  12/9/2014 0:00    12/9/2014 0:00
ajannett  4/14/2015 0:00    12/9/2014 0:00
ajannett  6/23/2015 0:00    12/9/2014 0:00
jakyles   12/9/2014 0:00    12/9/2014 0:00
jakyles   5/12/2015 0:00    12/9/2014 0:00
jakyles   6/23/2015 0:00    6/23/2015 0:00
```

I am trying to figure out why my FirstAttendanceDate column is returning "6/23/2015" for the user jackyles (which is not what I want) while user ajannett is returning the desired results. I am a fairly new user to SQL. Am I missing something fundamentally? Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you run only the inner SQL on its own, do you see just two records? Or do you see three?

Comment: Could you provide your testdata of all tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess, without seeing your original tables, has to do with the contents of the Name column as opposed to the CEC column. I suspect that if you add the Name column to your result set, the contents of that column for the last two lines will be different for the name column even though they are the same for the SQLCEC column.

My only suggestion would be to change your references in the query from Name to CEC:

```
SELECT [Attendees$].[CEC] AS [SQLCEC]
, [Attendees$].[Date] AS [SQL Date]
, [Data2].[FirstAttendanceDate]       

FROM [Attendees$]
INNER JOIN(SELECT [Attendees$].[CEC]
,                  MIN([Attendees$].[Date])As [FirstAttendanceDate]
                   From [Attendees$]
                   Group By [Attendees$].[CEC])AS [Data2]
ON [Attendees$].[CEC] = [Data2].[CEC]
WHERE [Attendees$].[CEC] IN ("jakyles","ajannett")
ORDER BY [Attendees$].[CEC],[Attendees$].[Date]
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight Bryan. You are absolutely correct. Upon further investigation, it appears that despite a person having a unique userid, their name was spelled differently.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.

```
SELECT [Attendees$].[CEC] AS [SQLCEC]

, [Attendees$].[Date] AS [SQL Date]
, [Data2].[FirstAttendanceDate]       

FROM [Attendees$]
INNER JOIN(SELECT [Attendees$].[CEC]
,                  MIN([Attendees$].[Date])As [FirstAttendanceDate]
                   From [Attendees$]
                   Group By [Attendees$].[CEC])AS [Data2]
ON [Attendees$].[CEC] = [Data2].[CEC]
WHERE [Attendees$].[CEC] IN ("jakyles","ajannett")
ORDER BY [Attendees$].[CEC],[Attendees$].[Date]
```

I was joining on name rather than CEC.

Comment: FYI, You can get this same effect in Tableau (starting with version 9), by using level of detail calculations instead of custom SQL.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore, sorry for the late reply. Yes, indeed! It wish I had read your post much sooner. It would have saved a lot of time.